# How to close Http URL Connection if IOException is caught? - Java

Tags: java, post, proxy, timeout

I am trying to make a script that send post request to a site using different proxies. Here is the method that send:

```
public static void send(boolean usingProxyB, int numberOfRequest, String ISP, String phoneNumber, String IP, Integer Port) {

    String url = "";
    String urlParameters = "";

    String ip;
    Integer port;


    if ( (ISP.toLowerCase()).equals("something") || (ISP.toLowerCase()).equals("something") || ISP.equals("something") ) {
        url = "https://www.something.com";
        urlParameters = "paramA=x&paramB=" + phoneNumber + "&paramC=y";
    }

    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    try {

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(IP, Port));
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);

        if (usingProxyB == true) {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection(proxy);
        } else if (usingProxyB == false) {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        }




        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "5000");
        System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout", "5000");

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java client");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        conn.getOutputStream().write(postData);

        conn.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("Success on sending SMS #" + numberOfRequest);


    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {

        System.out.println("A - Failed on sending SMS #" + numberOfRequest);

    } catch(ProtocolException e) {

        System.out.println("B - Failed on sending SMS #" + numberOfRequest);

    } catch(IOException e) {

        System.out.println("C - Failed on sending SMS #" + numberOfRequest);

    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

This code sends POST requests using different proxies or using my own ip. When I use the proxy list, it keep printing: "C - Failed on sending SMS #1". It doesn't change the proxy and it doesn't close the connection.

When the proxy doesn't work or it takes more than 5 seconds to send the request, I want to close the connection in the same way connection it is closed when it prints "Success on sending SMS #n". When I use my own IP, so I don't use a proxy list, it works correctly. The request is sent successfully and it continue by sending the other request.

I don't know if anything that I'm saying make sense, but I don't speak english very well.